# create filter from multiple data sources

Tags: tableau-api

I have multiple data sources that have city, state and country information.

Example -

```
Source 1:
ID      City        State       Country
12345   New York    New York    USA
12344   Cebu City               PHL
12232   Bengaluru   Karnataka   IND

Source 2:

ID      City    State    Country
12345   Dallas  Texas    USA
12344   London           UK
```

I would like to create a filter to show drill down option into country, state and city using both the databases. I cannot combine the source due to few sourcing issues. Not sure if a set can be created like union of the columns from the data sources to be able to show a filter that will have values from all the data sources.

Like..

Country = USA, PHL, IND, UK and then filter state and city and so on. 
Can someone please advise how I can achieve this?
The city, state and country columns are dynamic in my data sources

Comment: Try taking a look at the following link and see if it fits your use case: http://drawingwithnumbers.artisart.org/cross-data-source-joins-join-on-calcs-union-almost-anything-in-tableau-v10-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from Tableau's online help.

> You can union your data to combine two or more tables by appending values (rows) from one table to another. To union your data in Tableau data source, the tables must come from the same connection.
>
> If your data source supports union, the New Union option displays in the left pane of the data source page after you connect to your data.

It's pretty easy to do inside Tableau Desktop.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/union.html